# Error 500 script execution failure using header()

Tags: php, header

Instead of using input-hidden-fields, I build a query to pass variables to ipn:

```
  $query="cmd=_xclick&business=PAYPALKONTO-EMAIL&notify_url=http://IPNURL/ipn.php&return=http://ZURÜCKurlWENNbezahlt.de&
  cancel_return=http:/ZURÜCKurlWENNangebrochen.de&lc=DE&currency_code=EUR&custom=WERSTECKTEinformationenDIEmitGESENDETwerdenABERkeinerSIEHTzbPREISidODERnichts&
  item_name=Artikel&amount='".str_replace(",",  ".",  $_SESSION['1'])."'"; 

  ob_end_clean();
  header("Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?".utf8_decode($query));
  exit;
```

But when I click on submit, it stays on the same page and get `Error:500 "script execution failure"` Why is this? How can I fix this error?

Comment: most likely you have an error in your code, examine the servers error logs to get more information

Comment: Try building your query with `http_build_query` instead of building the string yourself - there might be encoding problems.

Comment: Why utf8_decode on a string that doesn't look like it needs it?

Comment: Are you sure thats a legal way of getting to PayPal, the usual way is to use cURL to post that data.

Answer (score 0):

Check your server logs for the exact error (or switch error reporting on in you php.ini to see the error message in the browser).

However, if the error is with the `header()` function, then the cause is almost always because you've already sent some other output to the browser first -- `header()` **must** be called before any of your page body is sent.

If you don't think you have sent any content, it may be a blank space that you've left unintentionally at the start or end of one (or more) of your PHP files.